# Correct meaning and usage of "ignorant"

Tags: synonyms, definition

I saw [the question about this word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15698/usage-of-the-word-ignorant), but it is more like an example of how not to use this word. From [definitions I found on google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ignorant), it looks like this word is used to describe someone who is not educated, or rude and unsophisticated.

But this sentence:

> They are ignorant, please teach them

seems awkward to me (I never saw this usage, it is just an example). So this word is probably used for someone who is uneducated **and rude/unsophisticated**. Am I right? Because translator to my language shows synonyms for words like `uneducated`, but from examples, it looks like it is not synonym with this word.

Answer (score 1):

*Ignorant* literally means *not knowing.* You can describe yourself as being ignorant **of** a particular subject or fact, but you have to be careful about calling someone else ignorant. Used on its own, it can have the sense 'uneducated, stupid' or even, as you say, 'behaving in an uncouth manner'.

So, it would be better to say

> They know nothing about XX, please teach them about it.

Comment: If I say _I'm ignorant of music theory_ , does that mean _I don't know about music theory_ , or _I don't know about music theory, so don't talk with me about this, because I hate it_ ?

Comment: It means you know nothing about it. There is no implication of not wanting to talk about it - you might go on to ask a question about it!

Comment: @LazarĐorđević: The most likely implication is probably *I know nothing about music theory [**and I'm not a native Anglophone**]*. See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+ignorant+of+the%2CI+am+ignorant+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). The difference is because ***to be ignorant of something*** is relatively "high register" (formal), so it doesn't pair well with the low register (informal) contraction ***I'm = I am***.